# How can I subtract a range of date of "Sysdate"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that is called "yesterday's tasks" and checks if today is Monday or not. If it's Monday, it gives me the tasks of the previous friday, and if not, of the day before.
Since we started to work on the week-end as well, I'd like that if it's monday, it will give me the tasks of friday, saturay and sunday.
That's my current code:

```
select
to_char(sysdate -0.25,'DAY') day,
t.task_id,
NVL (pu.part_id, 'NONE') part_id,
t.request_id,
(select(concat(concat (p.first_name, ' '), p.last_name)) from person p where t.person_id = p.person_id) name,
pu.quantity,
to_number(pu.user_def15, '9999999.99') lunch,
to_char(cast(t.actual_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH24:MI') started,
to_char(cast(t.actual_end_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH24:MI') ended,
NVL(pu.user_def2, 'MISSING') description,
case when NVL(pu.user_def2, 'MISSING') = 'MISSING' then '#FF0000' else '#000000' end description_c,
t.task_status,
to_char(t.plan_start_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD') start_date,
to_char (sysdate-0.25,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') today
from task t 
LEFT JOIN part_usage pu ON t.task_id = pu.task_id
where t.access_group = 'CAPCA'
and NVL(pu.part_id, 'NONE') IN ('030X001', '030A01','NONE')
and to_char(t.plan_start_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD') =
CASE WHEN
to_char(sysdate - 0.25,'DAY') = 'MÅNDAG '
THEN
 to_char (sysdate-3.25, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ELSE
 to_char (sysdate-1.25, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END
order by name
```

So I would like to modify the 'THEN" to have sysdate-3.25, 2.25 and 1.25.

Thank you

Comment: Where you are using this `case .. ` when? In where clause? Better if you can share whole query.

Comment: Hi @Alain, but this case code is one part of the story because it returns the date format of some kind. Where do you use that date ?

Comment: @Tejash, I just edited the question.The whole code is there now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
( (to_char(sysdate - 0.25, 'DAY') = 'MÅNDAG ' and
   t.plan_start_dttm >= trunc(sysdate - 3.25) and
   t.plan_start_dttm < trunc(sysdate - 0.25)
  ) or
  (t.plan_start_dttm >= trunc(sysdate - 1.25) and
   t.plan_start_dttm < trunc(sysdate - 0.25)
  )
)
```

I am not sure why you are converting dates to strings for comparisons.  That is a bad habit.  Oracle generally has enough date/time functions to support such comparisons.

Comment: I do it to be able to display only the date with this format (YYYY-MM-DD).
BTW, I'm not sure how to use your suggestion in my query above?

Comment: It replaces the comparison logic on  `to_char(t.plan_start_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  =`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: invalid relationship operator

Comment: @Alain . . . There was a typo -- a stray comma -- that I just removed.

Comment: I found another typo, second line there is a comma. But the quesry is still returning me only friday's tasks instead of friday, saturday and sunday.

Comment: @Alain . . . Are you sure you have the parentheses correct?  Are you sure you have tasks over the weekend?  Are you sure other logic in the query is not filtering them out?  The logic is here is that the date is compared to "Monday" and in that case, three days are included.  On other days, only the previous date is included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202584/discussion-between-alain-and-gordon-linoff).

Comment: @ Gordon. Have you seen my message?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `CASE .. WHEN` as following:

replace this portion of your query:

```
and to_char(t.plan_start_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD') =
CASE WHEN
to_char(sysdate - 0.25,'DAY') = 'MÅNDAG '
THEN
 to_char (sysdate-3.25, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ELSE
 to_char (sysdate-1.25, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END
```

with the following:

```
CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 0.25, 'DAY') = 'MÅNDAG ' THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN TRUNC(T.PLAN_START_DTTM) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3.25) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0.25) THEN 1
        END
    ELSE 
        CASE
            WHEN TRUNC(T.PLAN_START_DTTM) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0.25) THEN 1
        END
END = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This gives me the tasks of last friday and today.